# Per-project output directory with dotnet build (Azure DevOps)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I have a .NET Core solution with two projects (`proj1` and `proj2`). When I run a build in Azure DevOps, I use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 command like this:

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build output'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
```

As is, all the artifacts from both builds end up in the `publish_output` directory. What I'd like is for there to be a `proj1` and `proj2` subdirectory created under `publish_output` and the artifacts from the projects placed appropriately.

Is this possible? I could not find a "currently being build project name" variable to append to the output directory.

Comment: Have you tried the `modifyOutputPath` input? See the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish-projects-to-specified-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Simply Ged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2309376/simply-ged). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

Add `modifyOutputPath` as a input as below and check

[image]

Here is the code

```
# Publish projects to specified folder.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Output'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    modifyOutputPath: true
```

Follow the [Publish Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish-projects-to-specified-folder) for further instructions.

Comment: The wildcard also seems to be important